# Regex to replace character either before or after but not both

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove a span from a string and one of the dashes before or after like so:

```
1-2-3-<span>4</span>-5-6   => 1-2-3-5-6
```

However, the span can be at any position of this string:

```
<span>1</span>-2-3-4-5-6   => 2-3-4-5-6

1-2-3-4-5-<span>6</span>   => 1-2-3-4-5
```

So what I need is a regular expression to remove the whole span including one of the dashes (but not both) to maintain the correct syntax of the string (dash separated numbers).

This pattern works, but there must be an easier, nicer way:

```
'#-<span>[^>]+>|<span>[^>]+>-#'
```

I appreciate any hints!
Pete

Comment: Bobince in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: This might help you - `echo strip_tags('<span>1</span>-2-3-4-5-6');`

Comment: What about this? `#-<[^-]+>|<[^-]+>-#` .It's still working and it's a little smaller!

Comment: @GeorgeAnt - It's correct, but OP's just want to remove span tag I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`#-<[^-]+>|<[^-]+>-#`.

It's  still working and it's a little smaller!

Comment: Very nice expression! But still not what I'm looking for as it has the OR condition I am trying to avoid :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output like this - `1-2-3-4-5-6`, then you can use `strip_tags` method:

```
echo strip_tags('<span>1</span>-2-3-4-5-6');
echo strip_tags('1-2-3-<span>4</span>-5-6');
echo strip_tags('1-2-3-4-5-<span>6</span>');
```

Comment: I want to remove the number in the span entirely. So from this string: `<span>1</span>-2-3-4-5-6` I want this as a result: `2-3-4-5-6`

Comment: @Peter What would be the output for the above examples.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added the desired output to the original question.
prava: Yes, tested in regex buddy. This pattern matches either a dash followd by a span or a span followed by a dash. I'm not a big fan of OR if most of the pattern is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Check this DEMO:

http://codepad.org/0qsK3jmH

Use any set of input string you mentioned in your question and desired answer would be there on screen.

**This will cover all set of cases where a span with number can be in between , at start , or at the end.**

PHP code:

```
<?php
$input = "<span>4</span>-1-2-3-5-6";
 $processed1 = preg_replace("/<span>(\d+)<\/span>/", '',$input );
$processed2 = preg_replace("/--/", '-',$processed1);
$processed3 = preg_replace("/^-/", '',$processed2);
$output = preg_replace("/-$/", '',$processed3);
echo $output;



?>
```

Comment: That's indeed working, but I'm looking for the nicest, best performing solution (one line, regex as short as possible). I posted a working regex in the original post, which is already pretty short but not perfect imo because it contains an OR and repeating pattern.